# Django Rest Framework dynamic nested serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model, Parent which contains a Django ContentType GenericForeignKey relationship to various child models (ChildA, ChildB) in Parent.child

I'm trying to get ListCreateAPIView and other listing views working with this setup. Originally I handled the serialization of the child instance using a SerializerMethodField which looked something like:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_child')
    (other fields)

    def get_child(self, obj):
        if obj.content_type == "child_a":
            return ChildASerializer(obj.child).data
    ...
```

Now I want to take advantage of Django Rest Framework to its full (including deserialization/creation/validation) so I want to avoid my current approach and increase DRYness by doing:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (code for serializing parent fields except 'child' attribute)

class ChildASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (code for ChildA fields)

class ParentTypeASerializer(ParentSerializer):
    child = ChildASerializer()
```

If i'm reading the docs right, this means POST/PUT will go through the serializer's process without me having to override the post methods in views and other uglyness. This is important as ChildA,ChildB,ChildC come from plugins and the core Parent/ParentSerializer should be as unaware of them as possible.

My thinking was to override `get_serializer()` in the view, but when listing many objects, I don't see how I can provide ParentTypeASerializer, ParentTypeBSerializer etc in the view.

```
def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, files=None, many=False, partial=True):
    serializer_class = None
    if instance and instance.content_type == "child_a":
        serializer_class = ParentTypeASerializer
    if instance and instance.content_type == "child_b":
        serializer_class = ParentTypeBSerializer
    ...
    # What about many=True ?!

    return serializer_class(instance,data=data,files=files,many-many,partial=partial,context=context)
```

Another idea I had was to write a PolymorphicField class extending WritableField that does the decision. Unsure if this is the simplest approach:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = PolymorphicChildSerializerProxy()   # Passes through/wraps the right serializer
```

*question:* is there any dynamic/runtime/per-object way to provide the right serializer for an Generic/polymorphic nested object in such a way either at the view level or the parent serializer? Ideally something like the second example and an override in the view that works for List/Create/Destroy generics or like the first example except I return a serializer class rather than serialized data?

Comment: I know it's been a little while since you asked this, but could you share how did you end up solving this?

Comment: @Geekfish, I basically made a serializer for GenericForeignKey fields, but when you have thousands of them nested, caching is more important than any of the approaches for mixed-model serialization in DRF

Comment: What about: https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#manytomanyfield-foreignkey-onetoonefield